# Delta ignores JsonProperty

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a model using JsonProperty to set the PropertName, however, when using the Delta from Microsoft.AspNet.OData it ignores this. Has anyone found a different attribute or work around to get Delta to respect my PropertyName?

Ex:

Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JobsServer.Models {

  public class Job : Job{

    public long Id {get; set;}
    [Required, JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    public string Status {get; set;}
    [Required, JsonProperty(PropertyName = "region")]
    public string Region {get; set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "locality")]
    public string Locality {get; set;}
    [Required, JsonProperty(PropertyName = "country")]
    public string Country {get; set;}

  }

}
```

Patch Method

```
public IActionResult Update(long id, [FromBody] Delta<Job> jobPatch)
```

If I try to update status using 'status' it does not work, but using 'Status' works just fine. So, that property name seems to be being ignored.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729249/how-to-use-deltat-from-microsoft-asp-net-web-api-odata-with-code-first-jsonmed

Comment: I have not @AussieJoe, but that's also for an older version from back in 2013. As of just this month there's been a new version of microsoft's odata.