# PATCHing entities in Web API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, http-patch

I was wondering how to use the PATCH HTTP verb on my application since sometimes I don't need to update the whole entity.

The problem, is that in C# the lack of value is represented by null (there is not undefined like in JS).

So considering that I have this entity in my DB:

```
public class Dog
{
   public Int32 Id {get;set;}
   public String Name {get;set;}
   public String FamilyName {get;set;}
   public Int32 Age {get;set;}
}
```

And I use this entity to represent the data exchange in my endpoint:

```
public class DogInModel
{
   public Int32 Id {get;set;}
   public String Name {get;set;}
   public String FamilyName {get;set;}
   public Int32? Age {get;set;}
}
```

How do I PATCH an existing entity to set `FamilyName` to `null`, by only sending the `Id` and the `FamilyName`, without setting  the `Name` field no `null` in the process?

In other words, how can I design a model that informs me of the properties that the client is actually sending?

Cheers.

Comment: I feel like this may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177676/whats-the-currently-recommended-way-of-performing-partial-updates-with-web-api/14219403#14219403