# Getting an error while using partial updates in asp .net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am following this tutorial([What's the currently recommended way of performing partial updates with Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177676/whats-the-currently-recommended-way-of-performing-partial-updates-with-web-api)) to implement partial updates in my web api. But doing so i am getting an error:

```
  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object[]' because it is not a delegate type
```

This is my code for partial updates/patch :

```
   [AcceptVerbs("PATCH")]
    public user PatchDocument(int id, Delta <user> user)
    {
        var serverUser =db.users.Find(u => u.iduser = id); // This is where i get error Find(u => u.iduser = id)
        user.Patch(serverUser);

    }
```

Comment: `u.iduser = id` should that be `u.iduser == id`. Single `=` is assignment.

Comment: Even if i  use == , i get the same error

Comment: Can you show us what `db.users` contain?  And, by the way, why does your method signature say you return a `user` while the code seems to return nothing?  Are you still getting the error on the same line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try

```
var serverUser =db.users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.iduser == id);
if(serverUser != null)
{
    user.Patch(serverUser);
}
```

Edit Whoops needed ==

Comment: I am getting this error while using your code : Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<xxxx.Models.user,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: And Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm Could you try Adween's suggestion again (after he changed to ==)?

Comment: Error has changed now, now i am getting : not all code paths return a value

Comment: Yep @Halvard, i tried, now error is changed :not all code paths return a value

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm This is because you return nothing but your method signature says you need to return `user`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var serverUser = db.users.Find(u => u.iduser == id);  // == instead of =
```

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object[]' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Ok, so it did not fix the main error, but even so you need to use == instead of =

Comment: True , it was a mistake.